# nagiosplugin python package

Tags: python, nagios

For simplification of writing nagios plugins, I see Perl has a package called 'libnagios-plugin-perl' on Ubuntu systems.

Is there a similar Debian package for Python as well?

I looked at the nagiosplugin package at this link: 
Link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nagiosplugin/

But I can only install it using: # pip-3.2 install nagiosplugin

I was looking for help in understanding is there is a debian package for python similar to perl ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the below Debian package (in case someone is interested):

python-pynag                       0.7.0-1                      all          Python Modules for Nagios plugins and configuration

Comment: Maybe as a little clarification: Pynag is a "Python modules and utilities for Nagios plugins and configuration" while nagiosplugin is 'only' used to create plugins and focuses on that.

Comment: The pynag.Plugins provides a good template to create nagios plugins. So, I agree Pynag package provides other features than just simply providing a template for writing nagios plugins.